# Captcha on Contribution forms

Tags: civicontribute

I know that there is a Captcha function available for Profiles, but it seems that we have need for Captcha on contribution forms that do not use Profiles.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Profiles on contribution pages that contain an e-mail address will have that e-mail address suppressed.  So if you create a profile with just an e-mail address and add a CAPTCHA, you should get the results you're looking for.

Comment: Just ran into this ourselves.  I added a profile with just the email field, checked use recaptcha and added that profile to a contribution page but do not see any change to the page.

Comment: Doesn't work for CiviCRM 4.4 at least

Comment: You may not see a change to the page because you're not logged out.  Logged-in users never see a ReCAPTCHA.